# Pandas MultiIndex: how to align columns under column MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

My initial dataframe is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Core','PM2',1234,'Direct','2019-11-08 00:00:00','2019-11-08 00:59:59',3.300,'V'],['Long Term','Wind',1111,'Direct','2019-11-09 00:00:00','2019-11-09 00:59:59',0.00123,'V']], 
                  columns=['Program','Parameter','Station','Method','Start','End','Measurement','Flag'])
df
```

```
      Program   Parameter   Station Method                Start                 End Measurement Flag
0        Core         PM2      1234 Direct  2019-11-08 00:00:00 2019-11-08 00:59:59     3.30000    V
1   Long Term        Wind      1111 Direct  2019-11-09 00:00:00 2019-11-09 00:59:59     0.00123    V
```

I then index the dataframe:

```
df_index = df.set_index(['Start','End','Measurement','Flag'])
df_index
```

Which gives me:

```
                                                              Program   Parameter   Station Method
              Start                 End Measurement Flag                
2019-11-08 00:00:00 2019-11-08 00:59:59     3.30000    V         Core         PM2      1234 Direct
2019-11-09 00:00:00 2019-11-09 00:59:59     0.00123    V    Long Term        Wind      1111 Direct
```

I then create a MultiIndex for the columns:

```
df_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df_index[['Program','Parameter','Station','Method']])
```

Then I create a new dataframe with the MultiIndex:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(df_index, index=df_index.index, columns=df_columns)
data
```

This gives me:

```
                                                      Program     Core  Long Term
                                                    Parameter      PM2       Wind
                                                      Station     1234       1111
                                                       Method   Direct     Direct
              Start                 End Measurement      Flag       
2019-11-08 00:00:00 2019-11-08 00:59:59     3.30000         V      NaN        NaN
2019-11-09 00:00:00 2019-11-09 00:59:59     0.00123         V      NaN        NaN
```

What I want is to have the MultiIndex columns Program, Parameter, Station, and Method group each Measurement and Flag underneath it, leaving the Start and End as the index:

```
                                         Program       Core        Long Term
                                       Parameter        PM2             Wind
                                         Station       1234             1111
                                          Method     Direct           Direct
              Start                 End         Measurement Flag Measurement Flag
2019-11-08 00:00:00 2019-11-08 00:59:59             3.30000    V     
2019-11-09 00:00:00 2019-11-09 00:59:59                              0.00123    V
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that your output doesn't really make sense with your original Data. There is no Station = 1234 measurement on 2019-11-09 and yet your output suggest the value should be 0.00123.

Comment: Right.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I edited the desired output to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a series of stack/unstack:

```py
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Core','PM2',1234,'Direct','2019-11-08 00:00:00','2019-11-08 00:59:59',3.300,'V'],['Long Term','Wind',1111,'Direct','2019-11-09 00:00:00','2019-11-09 00:59:59',0.00123,'V']], columns=['Program','Parameter','Station','Method','Start','End','Measurement','Flag'])
df_index = df.set_index(['Start','End', 'Program','Parameter','Station','Method'])
df_index.unstack([-4, -3, -2, -1]).stack(-5).unstack(-1)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Works great!